# Nested lookup columns in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column

For some context, I work within a small design team who cover the whole of the UK. Our business also offer installation services, with various offices around the country.

I have a list, `Projects`, which contains all the projects our department is working on. One of the columns in the list is the county/city in which the works are being completed - `Area`. This is a lookup column to another list named `Areas`. The reason for a linked-list is so that we can store other information in the `Areas` list, such as local specifications etc, and so that the list of areas can be maintained separately.

I want to be able to create a view for the managers of all the individual installation teams to view all the projects we are working on in their area. The intention was to use the "*Add a column to show each of these additional fields*" checkbox within the `Projects` list, on the `Area` column, however this doesn't allow me to add a column of lookup type, or person/group type (the two types of column I have tried to use to store the details of the responsible manager).

I really don't want to hard code the managers contact details into the list item in the `Projects` list as it isn't anywhere near as maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of SharePoint lookup columns.

SharePoint lookup columns only support below column types:

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date and Time

**Documentation**: [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

---

**Workaround**:

You can write a Power Automate flow on item creation / update in Areas list and whenever the column changes in list, you can update the manager field in Projects list.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for the workaround - seems the cleanest solution.

Comment: You're welcome. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.