# REST API - Get lookup IDs of lookup column on second list through a lookup $expand on first list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, 2016, lookup-column

I have two lists, List1 and List2.

List1 has a lookup to List2, let's call it `List2Lookup`.

List2 has a multi-select lookup *to itself*, as a way to identify other items in the same list as "children", let's call that `List2SelfChildren`.

Is there a way to get the lookup IDs of the linked items in `List2SelfChildren` through a REST call to List1 and expanding the `List2Lookup` field?

If I do a REST call directly to List2, I can get back

```
{
    ID: 123,
    Title: "Something",
    List2SelfChildrenId: {
        results: [23, 56]
    }
}
```

where the `results` array is just the item IDs of the items selected in the lookup field, and again, that's all I really need to get, I don't need to expand any properties for items 23 or 56.

I've tried

```
/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items(7)?$select=ID,Title,List2Lookup/ID,List2Lookup,Title,List2Lookup/List2SelfChildrenId&$expand=List2Lookup
```

but that doesn't work.

I've also tried

```
$select=List2Lookup/List2SelfChildrenId/results&$expand=List2Lookup

$select=List2Lookup/List2SelfChildren/Id&$expand=List2Lookup

$select=List2Lookup/List2SelfChildren/Id&$expand=List2Lookup,List2Lookup/List2SelfChildren

$select=List2Lookup/List2SelfChildrenId&$expand=List2Lookup,List2Lookup/List2SelfChildren
```

and none of them work.

Is there some way for me to get those lookup IDs from the item in List2 by expanding the lookup from List1?

Comment: Unfortunately, No. You can extend/expand lookup column from lookup in SharePoint. So, you cannot get those details in single REST API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with single SharePoint REST API call. You can extend/expand nested lookup column details from lookup column in SharePoint list.

This is a known limitation of SharePoint lookup columns.

SharePoint lookup columns support simple column types for expanding via SharePoint REST API. For example:

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date and Time

**Similar thread**: [Nested lookup columns in a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299916/nested-lookup-columns-in-a-list/299917#299917)